# Trying to change value of variable by using html button, but something is wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to change the value of the variable `circle` by pressing on the button. The `click` function adds one to the value of `circle`. When `circle` is equal to `1`, my if statement should run the `changeColor` function that alters the right position of a `div`.

Here is my HTML code, the `click` function should run when pressed...

```
<div id="div"></div> <button onclick="click()">Click me</button>
```

I can add my css but it would just take up too much space and I doubt it would make a difference.

Here is my JS code...

```
var circle = 0;
function click(){ circle = circle++; }

function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("div").style.right="-500px"; }

    if (circle == 1){ changeColor(); }
```

Before I uploaded this question, I made sure that the `changeColor` function worked, by just changing `circle`'s value.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Where are you calling `changeColor()`.  I don't see it getting called anywhere.

Comment: Also, you can change your click function to just: `function click(){ circle++; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code that would *supposedly* call `changeColor()`, does not do so. When you load your page, that JavaScript is executed only once. Basically, your browser thinks like this...

`var circle = 0`

`// functions...`

`if(circle == 1) { ... }` "Nope, `circle = 0` right now, and `0 != 1`.

If you want to have the browser continually "listen" for the value of `circle` and run `if(circle == 1)` when value of `circle` is changed, the easiest way is to roll that `if` statement into your `click()` function:

```
function click() {
    circle++; // use this instead of circle = circle++;
    if(circle == 1) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks YOu so much, JS as a whole makes so much more sense now!!

Answer (score 1):

[click()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) is a pre-existing method, so HTML doesn't know you're talking about a function that you made. Also note that the *if statement* you use to check *circle* will only execute once, and before anyone ever has a chance to click the button; It needs to be inside the click function. And you don't need to redefine a variable after incrementing it, the increment alone will work.

```
function clicked(){
  circle++;
  console.log(circle,"it works!");
  if (circle == 1){
    changeColor();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya, I think it is calling window.click.